# How to configure systemd-boot to update boot menu order like Grub does?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, systemd

How to configure systemd-boot to load the current OS in the next boot?

I have a dual boot of Windows and Pop!_OS, and configured Pop!_OS as a default OS in Boot Menu. However, each time I open the Windows it updates the boot setting to load the Windows as default OS in next boot.

In Ubuntu, I was able to solve this problem by setting `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` in [Grub system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148662/how-to-get-grub2-to-remember-last-choice).

How to configure systemd-boot to overcome this windows feature or Is there any way to disable these Windows feature?

Comment: Please clarify: does the OS selection screen show up at all, but with Windows selected, or does it boot directly into Windows without letting you choose?

Comment: It directly boots to windows. And, I don't need OS selection screen as I mostly use Pop!_OS and whenever I need Windows I can go through BIOS Menu.

Comment: If that's the case then systemd-boot may not be involved at all - there can be something inside Windows that changes default boot order. It's a weird problem though, I have dual-booted Windows with Pop on multiple computers and never had this issue.

Comment: When, I go through the internet I found that Windows updates BIOS to load windows on next boot. And, GRUB_DEFAULT=saved in GRUB is somehow similar to this but, I couldn't find equivalent solution for systemd-boot.

Comment: if you have the timeout for systemd-boot set to 0 increasing that should at least present you the menu to select which OS to boot regardless of which is considered default.